# Pivot Tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem in Laravel that I believe requires a pivot table.  I have one table that lists all the potential options for a given plan.  It looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('category');
    });
}
```

Users can enter many plans and I need to keep track of the status (selected, unselected) for each of the options in each plan.  So the second table I think should look like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('selections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInt('plan_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('1');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('2');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('3');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('4');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('5');
        $table->unsignedBigInt('6');
    });
}
```

So, essentially, each plan has a row in the Selections table and the Selections table has a column for each option.

My problem is how I can then use this as a pivot table to return all the proper statuses in the view.  The view should have the option listed on one side if the status is 0 in the Selections table and the other side if the option is 1 in the Selections table.

Comment: So basically the relationship order is `User -> Plans -> Options -> Selections`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'm not sure how to properly design this.  I thought I could possibly create a new Options table for every plan and add a column for 'Status'.  That would make it easy to return information but it seems I shouldn't be creating all these tables.

Comment: Well there are few ways you can do it but it still depends on how you want it. e.g If you want all selections without trying to access plans, then you should add a `UserID` column to the `selections` table as well which you can then access through `hasMany`. It really depends on how you want to use it

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I know how to add the UserID column and create the hasMany relationship.  But, I don't know how to effectively put in my controller "pull the plan_id from the Selections table --> look at the status for each column (0 or 1) --> return the options from the Options table in the correct column based on the status

Comment: Ok I'm try understand the full scenario. So you would pull the `Selections` via `Plan` based on the `Status`. Furthermore, you would like to fetch all the `Options` based on the `Selections` status. Well, why not `Options -> Selections` but rather doing the reverse `Selection -> Options` of it. You can still filter both ways

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that sounds like it is on the right track.  But, I'm not sure how I could go from Selection->Options because I don't have a foreign key.  I will try to do a better job explaining:  The Options table is a static menu of options that a plan can either select yes or no to (0 or 1 in database).  The Selections menu has to hold all the selections for the given plan somehow.  It seems like I must create a row in Selections table for each plan, but I then don't know how to return what I need in my controller to show the options according to selection status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218684/discussion-between-basheer-kharoti-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

You need a many-to-many relationship between User model and Plan model

add this in User model

```
public function plans()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Plan::class, 'plan_user')->withPivot('user_id', 'plan_id);
}
```

add this in Plan model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'plan_user')->withPivot('user_id', 'plan_id);
}
```

Don't forget to add new table in the database with the 'user_id' and 'plan_id' columns